# tar extract zip archive from file or STDIN - discrepancy

Tags: windows, stdin, tar

Training to download and extract archive (zip archive, created by 7z) by

```
curl --output - "https://host.com/archive.zip" | tar -f - -C %dest_dir%
```

but archive extract is incomplete. Some compressed files and folders are missing in `%dest_dir%`. But when I perform

```
curl --output archive.zip "https://host.com/archive.zip" && tar -f archive.zip -C %dest_dir%
```

then the whole archive is extracted completely.

I suspect that antivirus silently delete some content, but AV log seems to be empty. Where could be a problem?

Comment: `stdin` for `tar` is probably in text mode instead of binary.  Welcome to Windows.

Comment: Lots of related questions, but I can't find a way to for `stdin` to be set to binary from the starting environment: [https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+start+process+with+stdin+in+binary+mode+site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+start+process+with+stdin+in+binary+mode+site:stackoverflow.com)  The only ones I've found so far involve code inside the process that is reading data from `stdin` explicitly setting the mode to binary.

Comment: And `stdout` for `curl` is probably in text mode, too.

Comment: Use `gunzip` with zip files or use option `--gunzip` with `tar`.

Comment: the archive is redistributable, so I need to use only windows build-in tools

Comment: @AndrewHenle thanks for this reasearch. Funny thing is, that it uncompress several files from archive, including executable binaries, but not other files including cmd script (almost plaintext).

Comment: @user2956477 Have you checksummed/hashed all the files to be sure the files that do get extracted have been done so correctly? IMO once anything in the extract fails, the entire set of extracted data is suspect.  You're not limited to only those tools you'll use in your build process when you're trying to determine what exactly is going on.